# Windows Search query c#

Tags: c#, sql, search, oledb, windows-search

I am trying to search for files containing a phrase or their name contains a phrase.

I achieved to get a query which sometimes has results but I do not get it when and why the results are returned.

This is the query I am using:

```
SELECT TOP 5 System.ItemPathDisplay 
FROM SystemIndex 
WHERE scope ='file:' 
    AND (FREETEXT('MYPHRASE') 
    OR Contains(System.FileName,'MYPHRASE'))
    AND (Contains(System.ItemType,'.txt') 
    OR Contains(System.ItemType,'.docx') 
    OR Contains(System.ItemType,'.pptx') 
    OR Contains(System.ItemType,'.xlsx') 
    OR Contains(System.ItemType,'.pdf'))
```

I just want to get all files containing the MYPHRASE name or having it in the content.

This is my oleconnectionstring:

```
  string connectionString = "Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties=\"Application=Windows\"";
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
```

can anyone tell me whats wrong with my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do a recursive search in your c# code like

```
    void DirSearch(string MYPHRASE) 
{
    try 
    {
       foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(MYPHRASE)) 
       {
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, txtFile.Text)) 
        {
           lstFilesFound.Items.Add(f);
        }
        DirSearch(d);
       }
    }
    catch (System.Exception excpt) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
    }
}
```

which comes from [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/303974) microsoft article which goes into good detail about how to do it with a full code example. Microsoft also offers a search [SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7388) which could also be helpful depending on your exact situation and may be worth checking out.

EDIT: [Here](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Using_Windows_Search_in_your_applications.aspx) is a nice blog about doing it in the sql style like you are, and you seem to be on point. he does mention how you may have to get files into the index for them to show up, so may be worth checking into.

Comment: How is the performance of the solution you offered? I also though about walking through the files myself, but I am a bit worried that this will be much slower. Do you have any information about this?

Comment: @adelpoint I honestly have no idea and have never done it myself, but Microsoft recommends it, so I'm assuming it's one of the better ways to do so.

Comment: I just tried it and the Problem is, that files like PDFs are not found by the solution. I think I need to use the System Index to query files like this ...

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got It working using the Blog you linked. my final query is: SELECT TOP 5 System.ItemPathDisplay FROM SYSTEMINDEX WHERE ((System.ItemType = '.pdf' OR System.ItemType = '.docx') AND FREETEXT('miau') )